# warning: Unable to read symbols for xxxx (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Not sure what this is about...  dns.so?
(I only have this problem on the iPod device... but the simulator works fine.)

This WARNING(NSLog) shows on installing the app on the iPod:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: No copy of dns.so found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

This ERROR(NSLog) shows up with the app running on the iPod:

```
2012-01-09 18:32:12.071 PlotData[868:307] Received memory warning. Level=1
2012-01-09 18:32:18.256 PlotData[868:307] Received memory warning. Level=2
```

Then the app crashes out... and sometimes locks the iPod entirely.